# In/out-error, lost document

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, filesystem-corruption

I had a document in a folder on a flash drive, and when I went to open it, it was nowhere to be found. Initially I thought it was something wrong with the USB stick where the folder was located, but when I tried to move other documents into the folder it was not possible and a In/out-error came up, saying it was impossible to move files into it, whereas in other folders it was completely fine. I can go into the folder, but it is completely empty.

So I started to think that this particular folder might have eaten my document. I also noticed an additional mysterious document I had never seen before outside of the folder, 0 byte and when it is opened, this window appears titled ASCII asking whether I want Unicode (UTF), what kind of type setting and what kind of language. I have tried to look for the document any place I could possibly imagine tmp folders, recently opened documents, but I can't find it.

Is there any way to open a larger history of recently opened documents in Libre Office in any kind of way, or is there any other way I could try to possibly recover the document?

The file system the flash drive is running on is ext3, and I tried `sudo fdisk -l` and then `sudo fsck /dev/sdc1` but it said:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
fsck: fsck.ntfs: could not be found
fsck: Error 2 when fsck.ntfs ran for /dev/sda1
```

I also tried `fsck.vfat`, could it work? Which alternative could work?

```
Output:
usage: fsck.vfat [-aAflrtvVwy] [-d path -d ...] [-u path -u ...]
device
-a automatically repair the file system
-A toggle Atari file system format
-d path drop that file
-f salvage unused chains to files
-l list path names
-n no-op, check non-interactively without changing
-p same as -a, for compat with other *fsck
-r interactively repair the file system
-t test for bad clusters
-u path try to undelete that (non-directory) file
-v verbose mode
-V perform a verification pass
-w write changes to disk immediately
-y same as -a, for compat with other *fsck
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: The drive is dying. Replace it.

Answer (score 1):

- In the future, don't save documents directly to removable media.
- Folders don't *eat* files.
- The I/O errors are a symptom that the drive is dying.
- If the partition is *ext3* why were you trying to run `fsck` with parameters for *ntfs* and *fat* filesystems?

**Try to recover the files using `photorec`**

Keep in mind it will not maintain the directory structure nor the filenames (and it uses metadata to guess the file extension). [Here's a step-by-step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)